# can't open only .scala.html file by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, playframework

Suddenly, I can't open *.scala.html but I can open other files in IntelliJ IDEA.
How can I fix it?

version: IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4

Comment: Have you tried restarting the tool, or even cleaning the project? this usually solves a lot of "small" problems (Just to be sure, can you edit any other Text-based file?)

Comment: @Bonatti Yes, I removed project directories, and re-clone and re-import project. But not recover.

Comment: I resolved the problem by myself.
1). quit IntelliJ
2). move preference directory for IntelliJ
   `mv ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea15 ~/Library/Preferences/bkup_IntelliJIdea15`    
3). restart IntelliJ and recreate default preferences

Comment: Nice to hear this. Please, close this question or writte down an answer to show other users how to fix the problem. (seems more like a glitch to me, so I suggest you close/erase this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by myself.

1. quit IntelliJ
2. move preference directory for IntelliJ
   `mv ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea15 ~/Library/Preferences/bkup_IntelliJIdea15`
3. restart IntelliJ and recreate default preferences